# SQL ordering by 2 columns

Tags: sql, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM `spells` WHERE Patch_No = '1.0.0.145' ORDER BY Spell_Type ASC, Champion ASC
```

This is what I am trying to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/svxdP.png
this result I get by clicking in PHP on column Spell_type first and then on Champion second

and using Query shown above I get this, everything mixed up
And here is what I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BSCm.png

Comment: Your results look totally reasonable.  I would suggest that you edit your question and include sample data and results *in the question*.  You can use a table format by putting four spaces at the beginning of each row.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to switch the ordering priority.
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `spells` WHERE Patch_No = '1.0.0.145' ORDER BY Champion ASC, Spell_Type ASC
```

Good luck